# Check if MySQL installed on server using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, server, php-extension

I am creating an installation script with PHP for my web application. I need to check requirements at the first. One of needed items is MySQL database.
Is `extension_loaded('mysql')` in PHP enough to make sure MySQL is installed on server? Or it only says about installed PHP extensions?

Comment: php cannot check if a mysql server is installed on a system. At least not in a general way. It can only try to connect as instructed and check if that succeeds. Reason is that there simply is no clear definition of what is actually meant by "if MySQL is installed on server".

Comment: @arkascha, but I think my question is clear.

Comment: No, it is not. Sorry. What exeactly does "is installed" mean? It might be that several mysql servers are installed locally and running. It might be that the user wants to use a mysql server installed on another system. Plus an installation (what does "installed" actually mean?) is defined different on various operating systems. And an installation alone says nothing, it has to be functional, the server has to be running too, has to accept connections sat all, has to accept connections from your php scripts, and and and. Just "if it is installed" certainly is _not_ clear.

Comment: Yes. You are right. specially when you said "It might be that the user wants to use a MySQL server installed on another system". I did not think about it. Thank you @arkascha for your comment.

Comment: @MohammadSaberi does "installed" implies that the server must be started and running? Formally it does not.

Answer (score -4):

try this

```
<?php if(!mysqli_connect()){ showerror(); } ?>
```

this one worked for me

Comment: Your solution does not answer the question if the mysql server is installed on the current server.

Comment: turnoff mysql server and try it

Comment: You did not provide any credentials. Even with mysql server up and running your connection would fail. Not to say that a server may not have `mysqli` installed.

Comment: downvote! if you turn off your mysql server it doesn't mean that it's not installed, it means that it's not running.

Comment: then downvote this question too. this one is working for me, thats all i know